# Server Error 500 While loading my index page in laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

please I don't know what else to be done. I created a resource controller and all was ok the create.blade was accessible and working fine, in fact, was saving to the database. even the index page was working before when it was just common HTML, but immediately I inserted the PHP details it starts loading server error 500. please see below:

**My index.blade**

```
      
        <div class="col-md-6" style="float:right">
                            <a href="{{ route('paymentdetails.create') }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded float-right">
                                <i class="fas fa-plus mr-2"></i>
                                @lang('Add Paymentdetails')
                            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive" id="users-table-wrapper">
            <table class="table table-borderless table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="min-width-80">@lang('Username')</th>
                    <th class="min-width-150">@lang('Amountpaid')</th>
                    <th class="min-width-100">@lang('Description')</th>
                    <th class="min-width-80">@lang('Created_at')</th>
                    <th class="min-width-80">@lang('Updated_at')</th>
                    <th class="text-center min-width-150">@lang('Action')</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @if (count($paymentdetails))
                        @foreach ($paymentdetails as $paymentdetail)
                        <tr>
                            <td class="align-middle">
                                <a href="{{ route('paymentdetails.show', $paymentdetail) }}">
                                    {{ $paymentdetail->username }}
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td class="align-middle">{{ $paymentdetail->amountpaid }}</td>
                            <td class="align-middle">{{ $paymentdetail->description }}</td>
                            <td class="align-middle">{{ $paymentdetail->created_at }}</td>
                            <td class="align-middle">{{ $paymentdetail->updated_at }}</td>
                            <td class="text-center align-middle">

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                                    <a href="{{ route('paymentdetails.show', $paymentdetail) }}" class="dropdown-item text-gray-500">
                                        <i class="fas fa-eye mr-2"></i>
                                        @lang('View Paymentdetails')
                                    </a>
                                </div>

                                <a href="{{ route('paymentdetails.edit', $paymentdetail) }}"
                                class="btn btn-icon edit"
                                title="@lang('Edit Paymentdetail')"
                                data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">
                                    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                                </a>

                                <a href="{{ route('paymentdetails.destroy', $paymentdetail) }}"
                                class="btn btn-icon"
                                title="@lang('Delete Paymentdetail')"
                                data-toggle="tooltip"
                                data-placement="top"
                                data-method="DELETE"
                                data-confirm-title="@lang('Please Confirm')"
                                data-confirm-text="@lang('Are you sure that you want to delete this user?')"
                                data-confirm-delete="@lang('Yes, delete him!')">
                                    <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    @else
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="7"><em>@lang('No records found.')</em></td>
                        </tr>
                    @endif
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My controller** from web

```
<?php

namespace Vanguard\Http\Controllers\Web;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\View\View;
use Vanguard\Http\Controllers\Controller;
Use Vanguard\Paymentdetails;

class PaymentdetailsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // dd("am here");
        return view('/paymentdetails.index');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('/paymentdetails/create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'username'=>'required',
            'amountpaid'=>'required',
            'description'=>'required',
            
        ]);

        $paymentdetails = new Paymentdetails;
        $paymentdetails->username = $request-> input('username');
        $paymentdetails->amountpaid = $request-> input('amountpaid');
        $paymentdetails->description = $request-> input('description');
        $paymentdetails->save();
        
        return redirect()->route('paymentdetails.index')
            ->withSuccess(__('Paymentdetails created successfully.'));
        // if($saveFlag){
        //     return redirect()->back();
        // }
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $paymentdetails = Paymentdetails::find($id);
        //dd($paymentdetails);
        return view('/paymentdetails/view')->with('paymentdetails',$paymentdetails);
    }
```

**My controller** from API

```
<?php

namespace Vanguard\Http\Controllers\Api\Paymentdetails;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Vanguard\Http\Controllers\Api\ApiController;
Use Vanguard\Paymentdetails;

class PaymentdetailsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // dd("am here");
        return view('/paymentdetails.index');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('/paymentdetails/create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'username'=>'required',
            'amountpaid'=>'required',
            'description'=>'required',
            
        ]);

        $paymentdetails = new Paymentdetails;
        $paymentdetails->username = $request-> input('username');
        $paymentdetails->amountpaid = $request-> input('amountpaid');
        $paymentdetails->description = $request-> input('description');
        $paymentdetails->save();
        
        return redirect()->route('paymentdetails.index')
            ->withSuccess(__('Paymentdetails created successfully.'));
        
        // if($saveFlag){
        //     return redirect()->back();
        // }
    }
    

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $paymentdetails = Paymentdetails::find($id);
        //dd($paymentdetails);
        return view('/paymentdetails/view')->with('paymentdetails',$paymentdetails);
    }
```

**my route(web)**

```
 /**
     * Paymentdetails
     */
    Route::resource('/paymentdetails', 'PaymentdetailsController')->middleware('permission:paymentdetails.manage');
```

Comment: you are not sending any data in the index.blade view for paymentdetails from yout PaymentdetailsController.

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: @mrhn 500 server error

Comment: There is an underlying error you can find in the log

Comment: @bhucho please how do you mean?

Comment: @mrhn please how can I find it

Comment: @bhucho have seen my error thanks, my index was meant to be like this: 
        `$paymentdetails = Paymentdetails::all();

        return view('paymentdetails.index')->with('paymentdetails', $paymentdetails);`     @mrhn thanks alot

Comment: as said in the log in the folder storage

Comment: @mrhn yeah! sure!